# Android change layout by sliding left/right

Tags: android, android-layout, scroll, slide

I tried many times to create a layout that contain multiple layouts and switch between these layouts by sliding left or right like on WhatsApp or Facebook apps.

I have used some LinearLayout, TableLayout and ScrollView but I didn't found the way to achieve it.

Do you have any solution please ?

Comment: Share some of your attempted code within your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you want to do is a Material Design Sliding Tabs ? I implemented that functionality in my app following this [guide](http://www.android4devs.com/2015/01/how-to-make-material-design-sliding-tabs.html)

Comment: I have an other question, when I am trying to create the toolbar with this xml code: 
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    
...
   
 android:theme="@style/Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
    
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />` 

An error occurs and tell me that it could not retrieve widget.toolbar... Is that because I am targeting an API below 21 ? @frankie015

Comment: @BilelBgr Your activity is extending ActionBarActivity ?

Comment: No, I have solved it last night by changing Build Path Properties of my project and appcompatv7, I am now targeting API 21 and it's working fine for me, thank you !

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use Androids ViewPager and set up your views as fragments, it has built in swipe gestures to transition through pages so should cover what you need.

Check out this example, it's also got a sample app you can download and test out:

http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html